# jQuery UI Sortable - change event of passive items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to catch a change event of jQuery UI Sortable on passive items, for example:

given this list:

```
1  
2  
3  
4
```

i move number 3 to the top:

```
3  
2  
1  
4
```

i changed the position of 3 elements, i want to catch the change event of all 3 of them (3,2,1)
currently i have a code for the start and change events like so:

```
start: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item.data('startPos') == null) {
            ui.item.data('startPos', ui.item.index());
        }
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
        var startPos = ui.item.data('startPos');
        var newPos = ui.placeholder.index();

        if (startPos != null && startPos != newPos) {
            ui.item.addClass('sort-dirty');
            ui.item.attr('data-newSortOrder', newPos);
        } else {
            ui.item.removeClass('sort-dirty');
        }
    }
```

But these events occur only on the single element i "touched" (3) and not the "passive" elements (1,2).
is there any public event to register for all items that changed position?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aminur/ttraem8n/2/) demonstrating event firing with each element changed position while dragging an item. On those event fire, I've log these in console, so that you can check they are working properly. `start( event, ui )` event fired when user starts dragging an item and `change( event, ui )` event fired when each item get moved by the starting item.

Comment: did you check my answer?